# AnnotationConfigApplicationContext register & refresh another configuration class

Tags: java, spring

I'm pre initializing an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (register + refresh) inside a service locator (Singleton) with a configuration class (mock).

When I start my application I set a configuration class property. I would like to replace the configuration class already registered and reload my configuration.

As "refresh" method can be uses once, is it possible or may I set directly at init the correct configuration class ?

Config class 1

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxx.core.service.ws.controller" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class ContextCoreMockConfiguration {
}
```

Config class 2

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource(value={ "classpath:sessionFactory-datasource-spring.xml"} )
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxx.core.service.impl"
                              , "com.xxx.core.dao.impl" })
public class ContextCoreServiceConfiguration {
}
```

Singleton initializing context

```
public class AnnotationContextCoreLocator { 
    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  context; // Context IOC

    private AnnotationContextCoreLocator() {
        this.context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        this.context.register(ContextCoreMockConfiguration.class);
        this.context.refresh();
    }


    /**
     * Context
     * @return AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
     */
    public static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE.getContext();
    }

    /**
     * singleton instanciation
     * @author asi
     *
     */
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        static final AnnotationContextCoreLocator INSTANCE = new AnnotationContextCoreLocator();
    }

    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

The idea is to be able at runtime to change configuration class of Singleton

```
String configCoreClass = servlet.getInitParameter("contextCoreConfigurationClass");
AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().register( Class.forName(configCoreClass) );
AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().refresh();
```

Problem is that "refresh" method can be used once. I could remove "refresh" from my Singleton and do it at 1st use but I would like to change injection at runtime.

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: I feel you need to rethink the entire idea of refreshing an existing context. What if a particular bean is already injected somewhere, you reinitialize the context again with configuration that doesn't contain that bean. What would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

So the onyl solution I found is not to initialize context in Singleton. But set it when my servlet starts.

Singleton :

```
public class AnnotationContextCoreLocator { 
    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  context; // Context IOC

    private AnnotationContextCoreLocator() {
        this.context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        //this.context.register(ContextCoreMockConfiguration.class);
        //this.context.refresh();
    }

     .....

     }
```

Servlet init

```
String configCoreClass = servlet.getInitParameter("contextCoreConfigurationClass");
AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().register( Class.forName(configCoreClass) );
AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().refresh();       
AdherentService adherentService = AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().getBean(AdherentService.class);
...
```